# default value 0 in migration ignore request value laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, migration

i have table (Products)

Products table has three columns ( id , product_name , product_quantity )

i want product_quantity column by default set value 0 if input left empty

this is migration code :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('product_name');
        $table->integer('product_quantity')->default('0');
        
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

this is ProductsController code :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    
    $rules = [
        'product_name' => 'required',
       //  'product_quantity' => 'nullable',
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        
        'product_name.required' => 'please insert product name ',
      
    ];

    Product::create($this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages));

    return back();
}
```

and this Product Model code :

```
Protected $fillable = ['product_name' ,'product_quantity'];
```

but when i store a request with any value , it ignore the value and save the default (0)

Comment: is `product_quantity` set as "fillable" on the Model?

Comment: yes i set product_quantity as "fillable" on the Model

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must be careful about the values you set in migration's `default()` method. If you are using an `integer` type, it is not correct to pass a `string` in `default()`:

```php
$table->integer('product_quantity')->default(0); // turn the '0' into 0
```

The other observation is `$this->validate()` method only returns an array of validated data, so if you have commented the validation rule for  `product_quantity`, it will never be passed to `Product::create()`. With that said, the database is not receiving `product_quantity` value, so it sets to default (0).

If you want `product_quantity` to be passed to `Product::create()` you must uncomment the rule for that value.

I hope this explanation helps you.

Comment: when i uncomment the validation rule for product_quantity , i get error Column 'product_quantity' cannot be null , this error i get when i left input empty

Comment: Yes, that is because you are validating that product_quantity can be null, so now it is returned by the $this->validate() method when the value is null and passed to create() method, so laravel is trying to insert a null value when  it must be an integer

Comment: Don't send the product_quantity key in the request and change the rule from nullable to `numeric`, this way you will force the product_quantity to be intenger when present and not taking care of it when it is not present, so default will be set